# Excel Formula Traduction (multilingual system)

Tags: excel, vba, internationalization

I am currently programming KPIs on Excel, my VBA code creates references to external Excel sheets (extracted from SAP) using code lines like `Wb.Ws.Cells(i,j).FormulaLocal = "=IF(InternalRef = 0; None; ExternalRef)"`. I also use the `SUM()` function the same way.

Now this works perfectly and does what I want, the problem is that I work in Switzerland, and the firm is bilingual (French and German). Being French, my Excel is in French, transforming the `IF()` Excel function to `SI()` and `SUM()`to `SOMME()`.
Using `SI()` and `SOMME()` makes the code work on my computer, but fails on German ones (where `IF()`and `SUM()` have to be used), and my KPIs have to work under both languages.

How do I traduct those functions to get a "universal" code ?

Thank you for your help, Mirage

**Edit :** `IF()`and `SUM()` are not recognized by French Excel

Comment: Usually vba recognises the English names whatever the language installed. Do a search on here as this has been asked and answered a couple of times. . What you could also do is to test for the language then use either the French names or German names...

Comment: Use `Formula`, not `FormulaLocal` and supply the formulas as they would be entered on a US computer: i.e. English function names and commas as the argument separators.

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for your answer. As I said in the edit, I tried with the english names on my PC and it doesnt work (it does the same as if I was using french words on german computers). Sadly I couldn't find a topic answering it, but I'm kind of a noob in here so I may have done it wrong.

Comment: Rory is right. The way to resolve your issue is to use `Formula` with english notation. This should work on every computer no matter of localization and globalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rory is right!

Rather than this:

```
Wb.Ws.Cells(i,j).FormulaLocal = "=IF(InternalRef = 0; None; ExternalRef)"
```

use this:

```
Wb.Ws.Cells(i,j).Formula = "=IF(InternalRef = 0, None, ExternalRef)"
```

**Note:**

As you can see, in English notation - a comma `,` is used instead of `;`.

**Tip:**

To display English notation of formula in active cell, use:

```
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Fomula
```

Comment: Nice tip on the debug.print active cell.formula